# htmlunit button clicked but server responds as though different button clicked

Tags: java, htmlunit

(Wow, I didn't realize how hard it is to get help here. If anyone sees how this question can be better posed, I'm open to suggestions)

Stated briefly, I use HtmlUnit to load a page, alter fields and .click() the 'submit' button.  However the server always responds with the page that would be the returned if a different button on a different form had been clicked.

The obvious answer is I must be selecting the wrong form or wrong button.  However over the weeks I've used many different semantics to select the button and many tests to verify it is indeed the correct button on the correct form.

I've used this site for months now to learn all manner of things, think you everyone. 
But this one's had me stumped for weeks.

Here is the condensed web page I'm trying to work with:

```
<HTML>
...

<FORM ACTION="http://www.awebsite.com/search.asp" METHOD="POST">
...
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Go!">
...
</form>

...

<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="inventory.asp?a=sd&blindID=252">
...
<INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Go!">
...
</form>

...

<FORM ACTION="inventory.asp?pg=1&blindID=252&a=c&viewPrices=" METHOD="post">
...
<INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Submit Changes" onClick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit()">
...
</form>

...
</HTML>
```

And my java program fragment for processing it:

```
// call my own external routine for getting web pages
HtmlPage page = webFetch.fetchWithCookies("http://www.awebsite.com/inventory.asp?blindID="+blindId, validator, filename); // get page with forms on it

// modify an input field
inpPrice = page.getElementByName("newPrice"+item.lotId);
inpPrice.setValueAttribute(item.price.toString());

// submit modified page to server
List<HtmlForm> forms = page.getForms();
HtmlForm form = forms.get(2);
HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Submit Changes");
HtmlPage page2 = button.click(); // get the server response page

// save the returned page locally so we can look at it
File saveFile = new File("page2.htm");
if (saveFile.exists()) {
    saveFile.delete();
}
page2.save(saveFile);
```

I want the third form, but everything I do gets me the response from the second form.  Things I have tried:

- I use setJavaScriptEnabled(false);  Because when I turn it on I get masses of errors I can't understand.
- BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6   None of the 'browser' constants make any difference.
- I tried using .type('\n'); on one of the field inputs in the form.  No difference.
- Tried forms.get(3) just to make sure I was getting the last form in the list, in case there were hidden forms I didn't see.  That appropriately got me an IndexOutOfBoundsException error, indicating only 3 forms were picked up.
- Turned javascript off in my modern Firefox browser and tried executing the exact same steps I'm trying to accomplish with HtmlUnit.  Server returned correct and expected page as though correct button was pressed.  This would seem to imply that javascript is not needed and therefore not the source of my troubles?

Comment: and when you inspect during debug you can see that this is the right form?

Comment: Many times.  The form and button always look correct. -  What happened the answer provided by someone else, was it deleted?

Comment: and did you check the HTTP request, what is really being sent and to which resource?

Comment: Ah, no I didn't.  It sounds good but I don't know how or what tool to use.

Comment: you can use [NetTools](http://nettool.sourceforge.net/) and make a kind of local proxy in what your page will refer the local proxy address:port and the proxy will refer the correct server:port

Comment: It turns out that figuring out how to make NetTools setup a local proxy and getting the java program to communicate through that proxy isn't any small task.  I tried just monitoring the HTTP packets but could get no useful information.